# Sum column based on another columns values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which represents grayscale image

```
+---+---+-----+
|  w|  h|color|
+---+---+-----+
|  0|  0|255.0|
|  0|  1|255.0|
|  0|  2|255.0|
|  0|  3|255.0|
|  0|  4|255.0|
|  0|  5|255.0|
|  0|  6|255.0|
|  0|  7|255.0|
|  0|  8|255.0|
|  0|  9|255.0|
|  0| 10|255.0|
|  0| 11|255.0|
|  1|  0|255.0|
|  1|  1|255.0|
|  1|  2|255.0|
|  1|  3|255.0|
|  1|  4|255.0|
|  1|  5|255.0|
|  1|  6|255.0|
|  1|  7|255.0|
+---+---+-----+
top 20 rows
```

For each row I need to sum "color" when values from "w" and "h" are in range from current value to current value plus a number.

To better understading, possible solution would look like this:

```
val windowW = Window.rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.currentRow + num1)
val windowH = Window.rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.currentRow + num2)

df.withColumn("color_sum", sum(col("color")).over(col("w").windowW and col("h").windowH))
```

Could you please give me some hints how to achieve this calculation?

Expected output for the very first row:

```
+---+---+-----+----------+
|  w|  h|color|sum(color)|
+---+---+-----+----------+
|  0|  0|255.0|      1020|
+---+---+-----+----------+
```

Where num1 and num2 are both equals 1.

That means sum is taken from rows:

(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)

For row (1, 1) sum would be taken from rows (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2).

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: I just edited the question with expected output

Comment: So in this case you want to sum of the next 4 rows ? rows with (w,h) = (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use window functions to apply a function on 2-dimensional data with these constraints.

You can use the join method to find the rows:

```scala
df.as("df1")
  .join(df.as("df2"),
    ((col("df1.w") - col("df2.w") <= 0) && col("df1.w") - col("df2.w") >= -1) &&
      ((col("df1.h") - col("df2.h") <= 0) && col("df1.h") - col("df2.h") >= -1),
    "inner"
  )
  .groupBy("df1.w", "df1.h")
  .agg(min("df1.color") as "color", sum("df2.color") as "sum")
  .orderBy("w", "h")
  .show()
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks.
However the 1st and 3rd condition should be "<= 0"